# Where can I find documentation of the 'keypress' event in Node.js

Tags: node.js

In Node.js, we can configure the `'readline'` module to emit `'keypress'` events like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);

if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
}
```

Then, we can listen to keypress events like this (example listens to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> ):

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

This works very well, but I can't find any documentation about the `'keypress'` event at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/.

So my question is: where is the documentation about the arguments used when my `'keypress'`-callback is called?

Comment: Might be the MDN reference could help also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

Comment: you can read the documntation here :--- https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_write_data_key

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This detail is specified [here](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_write_data_key) because:

The `process.stdin` is a duplex stream and calling `emitKeypressEvents(<IN/OUT>)` will cause that `readline` module will read from the `process.stdin` then it will parse the data and then will emit the event writing to the `output` stream calling `write`, because of this the docs you are looking for are written on that function.

`emitKeypressEvents` set the same input param as input and output, instead in `createInterface` you can define one for input and one for output (where you must attach the `on(keypress)` event.

A little playground to understand:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const inStream = new Readable({
  read() { console.log('in reading'); }
});

let i = 0
setInterval(() => { inStream.push(`${i++}`) }, 1000)
readline.emitKeypressEvents(inStream);

inStream.on('keypress', (...ar) => {
  console.log(ar)
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, would never have found it there...

A link from [emitKeypressEvents documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_emitkeypressevents_stream_interface) to [rl.write documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_write_data_key) would be a real improvement.

Comment: Also thanks for the additional info and playground 

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly documented, but the `readline.emitKeypressEvents()` method causes the given Readable stream to begin emitting `keypress` events corresponding to received input:

- https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_emitkeypressevents_stream_interface
- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

Comment: Thanks for your hints, I also found this documentation but it does not link to the keypress event's documentation. Turns out, that it's part of the `rl.write` documentation like described in [this answer I accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182456/1814576).

Answer (score 1):

you can read the documntation here :---

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_write_data_key

and little info about

The **process.stdin** is a duplex stream and calling **emitKeypressEvents()** will cause that readline module will read from the **process.stdin** then it will parse the data and then will emit the event writing to the output stream calling write,because of this the docs you are looking for are written on that function.

The **readline.emitKeypressEvents()** method causes the given Readable stream to begin emitting '**keypress**' events corresponding to received input. This is automatically called by any readline instance on its input if the input is a terminal. Closing the readline instance does not stop the input from emitting 'keypress' events.

```
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
      if (process.stdin.isTTY)
      process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
```